# Python: How can we match values of predicted and truth values of a regression model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, random-forest

We are trying to plot the predicted values and truth values on the same graph after fitting a model to predict a truth value using a `RandomForestRegressor` in `Python` of the [three column dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ajk8jGD1OxSEl2cnF6TC1lUXM) (click the link to download the full `CSV`-dataset formatted as in the following

```
t_stamp,X,Y
0.000543,0,10
0.000575,0,10
0.041324,1,10
0.041331,2,10
0.041336,3,10
0.04134,4,10
0.041345,5,10
0.04135,6,10
0.041354,7,10
```

Here is how we do the prediction.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob, os
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import math
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "data*.csv"))))

for i in range(1,10):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(10)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values
y = df['Y'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)


reg = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse')
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)


modelPred_test = reg.predict(X_test)

print(modelPred_test)
```

For comparison, we wish to generate a plot before prediction and after prediction. For the truth value, we tried it with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['time'].values, df['Y'].values)
```

We wish to plot (in the same graph) the ground truth (`time` as x-axis and the value of `Y` as y-axis. When we do

```
ax.plot(df['time'].values, modelPred_test)
```

We are getting the following error.

```
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

This means that we have less prediction values than we have time stamps in our dataset. To verify this, I did
`print(df['time'].values.shape)` and `print(modelPred_test.shape)` - and it outputs `(258523,)` and `(103410,)` respectively. How can we match which of my time values correspond to the prediction values, then i can use a subset of the time values for my plot command?

Comment: You can pass `np.arrage(df.shape[0])` to `train_test_split` and use "test" part as index for `df['time'].values` in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your data like the following.

```
X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)
X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)
```

and then sort the datasets

```
index_values=range(0,len(y_test))
y_test.sort_index(inplace=True)
X_test.sort_index(inplace=True)
modelPred_test = reg.predict(X_test)
ax.plot(pd.Series(index_values), y_test.values)
```

finally, do the same plot for the predicted values of `y`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the indices for training and testing datasets. For example, you could define

`train_index, test_index = train_test_split(df.index, test_size=0.40)`

and then `X_train = X[train_index]`, etc.

Then, you could plot the results via `ax.plot(df['time'][test_index].values, modelPred_test[df.index == test_index])`.

Comment: Could you try `X_train = df.X[train_index].values`, etc. (In the same spirit as you have just mentioned?)